# Sending Open Sound Control (OSC) in Android Studio, socket error

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, osc

I tried to use OSC in android studio, following by "Tutorial: Android OSC Communication" on http://courses.ideate.cmu.edu/physcomp/f14/16-223/tutorial-android-osc-communication/. It uses JavaOSC from Illposed.

However, I got a socket exception error when I created a new OSCPortOut. Can you share some idea of what is happening here? How to solve this.

Android studio 1.5.1
Version 4.4
Many thanks

```
package com.jiajunyang.emosoundcontrol1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.illposed.osc.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // init IP and port
    private String myIP = "192.168.11.93";
    private int myPort = 5000;

    // This is for sending messagign.
    private OSCPortOut oscPortOut;

    // This thread will contain all the code for OSC
    private Thread oscThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                // Connect to IP and port
                oscPortOut = new OSCPortOut(InetAddress.getByName(myIP), myPort);
            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.d("OSC2", "OSC Port Out UnknownHoseException");
                //Error handling when your IP is not found
                return;
            } catch (SocketException e){
                Log.d("OSC2", "Socket exception error!");
            }
//            } catch (Exception e){
//                Log.d("OSC2", "OSC Port Out Other error");
//                // Error handling for any other errors.
//            }

            /* 2nd loop infinitely and send messages every x ms.
            * */
            while (true){
                //Log.d("OSC2", "Beginning to while loop");

                if (oscPortOut != null){
                    // Creating the messages
                    Object[] m2send = new Object[3];
                    m2send[0] = "Hello";
                    m2send[1] = 100;
                    m2send[2] = 1.23;

                    OSCMessage message = new OSCMessage(myIP, Arrays.asList(m2send));

                    try{
                        Log.d("OSC2", "Successed to send");
                        // Send messages
                        oscPortOut.send(message);
                        // Pause
                        sleep(500);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("OSC2", "Failed to send.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        oscThread.start();



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I now added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> in the manifest.xml file. Now the error say my IP is not a valid OSC address . Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and finally figured it out.
OSC uses the term address twice, once as a INetAddress (an IP address), and again in an OSCMessage. An OSCMessage address is just a string for the receiver to listen for, but it must start with a "/"

---

change your line:

```
    OSCMessage message = new OSCMessage(myIP, Arrays.asList(m2send));
```

to:

```
    OSCMessage message = new OSCMessage("/msgAddress", Arrays.asList(m2send));
```

---

at the receiver:

```
    receiver.addListener("/msgAddress", listener);
```